# How to use multi-line string for Kivy button?

Tags: python, kivy

I wrote the following code in Python's Kivy.

When executed, a simple GUI with only one button will launch.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string("""
<TextWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size

        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "test multi-line"
            font_size: 48
            on_press: root.buttonClicked()
""")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.properties import StringProperty 

class TextWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TextWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        print('test')

class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = 'testApp'

    def build(self):
        return TextWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

[image]

The text for this button is written on a single line, but I really want to split the characters into two lines, as in the image below.

[image]

When I rewrote `text: "test multi-line"` to `text: "test \ n multi-line"` and ran it, I got an error.

The details of the error are as follows.

```
 kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 10:
 ...
       8:            id: button1
       9:            text: "test
 >>   10: multi-line"
      11:            font_size: 48
      12:            on_press: root.buttonClicked()
 ...
 Invalid indentation, must be a multiple of 4 spaces
```

Is it possible to use multiple lines of text for Kivy buttons?

Comment: Try using "test\\nmulti-line" (two backslashes).

Comment: Using `"""` might also work in kv, not sure.

Comment: Thank you,\\n is work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go buddy, this should solve your issue

```
id: button1
text: "test\nmulti-line"
font_size: 48
on_press: root.buttonClicked()
```